# How to change individual values in a Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.Series([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1])
test_df[0] = 1
```

How do I change the first value in this series to a one? It doesn't work as a list does. I tried using the .replace method but I only want to change a single value, not all of them.

Comment: Your code is fine, what is the problem?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `loc`

```
test_df.loc[0] = 1 
test_df
Out[140]: 
0     1
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     0
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: His current code is fine